# Calling Function creates Error: 'startCalender' is not defined. (JS + React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

When running my script I get the error that my function is not defined. I think I am creating or calling my function inside of the Class incorrectly.

This one is supposed to be an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) but I'm not sure if thats possible inside of a class. (The second part where StartCalender() is called is in another function in my script)

```
  startCalender = ((month) => {
    //contents
  })();


  startCalender(//variable);
```

The other function causing the same error I tried as an arrow function but changed it to see if it would fix the error:

```
  changeMonth(changeAmount) {

    //contents

    startCalender(//variable);
};
```

This is called in the return() of Render():

```
<BiLeftArrowAlt className="arrowIcon leftArrow" onClick={() => changeMonth(-1)}/>
```

This is just an Imported FontAwesome component which calls the previous function when clicked.

Comment: `setState` is a *method*, you must call it, not assign to a property of it. In order to refer to a property of an object, put a dot between the object and the property. `this.changeMonth`

Comment: That probably fixes something but the error i'm getting refers to calling the function specifically, not its contents: 'changeMonth' is not defined. I'm asking about calling the function correctly not about using state

Comment: *In order to refer to a property of an object, put a dot between the object and the property. `this.changeMonth`*

Comment: @CertianPerformance Thanks, It doesn't fix the error but it helps anyways.

Comment: It should. `this` will be defined when rendering, so accessing an existent property of the instance will work, assuming `changeMonth` is really defined as a method of the class (or as a class field)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thats the issue, It says that 'changeMonth is not defined'

Comment: Sounds like you still aren't referring to it as a property of the instance, but as a standalone variable. No such standalone variable exists.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Even if I delete all of the functions contents, I still get the same error. Something is wrong with the Function or how I call it (probably syntax) but don't see the error

Comment: I've explained it multiple times by now, please read the comments again... you cannot refer to a property of an object as if it was a standalone variable, since it's not a standalone variable

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry, I really don't understand what you're saying. What do you suggest changing in the code to fix it? Like can you tell me exactly what I need to type to fix this?

Comment: if you are referring to startCalender = ((month)... The following function which is just a standard function doest run either

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry, I'm so stupid. That actually fixed it... I was changing the variables stored in state to this.stateValue. Anyways thanks for the help.